# Creating forms that only certain users can see.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, private

I am relatively new to ruby on rails, however this isn't my first project. I am trying create an event management website where the organiser can log in and populate a form with users information and an email address. The users then receive an email allowing them to pay whatever fee is due at the end. I'm using devise cancan and rolify and have setup 3 roles.

Basically I am unsure how to make the form private so only members that are included in the party can see the form and pay the amount.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like that:

```
class PartyController < ApplicationController
  def view_payment_form
    unless current_user.has_role?(:member, Party.find(params[:id])) 
      flash[:error] = "You are not a member"
      redirect :back
    else
      # do what ever is needed to display form
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Im not overly worried about the payment side of things, what i'm trying to do is sort it that there could be multiple organisers and multiple events happening but people associated with a certain event will be able to see only that list of people. Its the theory of what I need that gets me!!!       Thanks for your comments thus far

Answer (score 1):

CanCan's author, Ryan Bates, has [several excellent RailsCasts on authorization](http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=26) -- if you're relatively new to Rails, it's the best $9 you'll ever spend :-)  I am pretty sure Rails would no longer exist without Railscasts :-)

Maybe also see the link in a comment I added below.

Update: removed advice to use CanCan as I missed that the OP was already using it.

Comment: @Matt yes, you're right, my bad -- I updated the answer.  While I think the screencasts are excellent, here's a tutorial that is perhaps too much, but [provides good examples of how to use all three tools, CanCan, Devise, and Rolify together](http://railsapps.github.com/tutorial-rails-bootstrap-devise-cancan.html).

Answer (score 0):

CanCan's main feature is that you can hide all the authorization code in a single class, which includes  `CanCan::Ability` class. In the simplest case you just call that class `Ability`.

If you already use CanCan you know that in that class you define the `initialize` method. In your case it may look something like this:

```
class Ability

  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

    can :manage, :party do |party|
      party.members.include? user
    end
    can :read, :all
  end
end
```

This code will already make sure that only a member can manage (:update, :create, :destroy) a Party. So even if a form on a page would be visible to everyone, the controller would return error if a non-member would submit it.

But of course, you want better than that, so in the particular view you could add a check:

```
<% if can? :manage, @party %>
  <%= form_for @party do |f| %>
    <!-- your form here -->
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Where `@party` is a particular instance you want to edit.